# How to aggregate the rows of a table to create a new one in sql

Tags: sql, aggregate, distinct, aggregation, vertica

I am working with sql and I would like to do the following.
I have a table

| Name | Limit | Use |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | 100 | 50 |
| Person1 | 200 | 200 |
| Person2 | 200 | 0 |
| Person3 | 100 | 100 |
| Person3 | 200 | 50 |
| Person3 | 300 | 50 |

And I want as a result

| Name | Limit | Use |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | 300 | 250 |
| Person2 | 200 | 0 |
| Person3 | 600 | 200 |

This means I want to create a table that has only one row for each distinct name and aggregates the rows for each different name by summing them.
Would be happy for any help!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is "aggregation". Use a [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause and then add the values together with the aggregate function [`sum`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp).

```
select
  name,
  sum(limit) as limit,
  sum(use) as use
from that_table
group by name
```